# python: if elif else works incorrect..?

Tags: python-3.x

I have python 3.4.3
If I use:

```
import platform
platform.architecture()
```

The result is:

```
('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
```

I have simple program (just for me and just for test):

```
import platform
import time
import os

system_arch = []
windows = "Windows" or "windows"
linux = "Linux" or "linux"

try:
    platform.system()
    a = platform.system()    
    if a == windows:
        platform.architecture()
        if ("64" in os.getenv('PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE')) in platform.architecture():
            system_arch += [platform.system()]
            system_arch += ['64-bit']
        elif ("32" in os.getenv('PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE')) in platform.architecture():
            system_arch += [platform.system()]
            system_arch += ['32-bit']
        else:
            system_arch += ['win_test_ok']
    elif a == linux:
        system_arch += ['linux_test_ok']

    else:
        system_arch += ['system_error']
except:
    TypeError, AttributeError

print(system_arch)
time.sleep(7)
```

The result is:

```
['win_test_ok']
```

BUT! If I duplicate with 'or', I mean:

```
if ("64" in os.getenv('PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE')) or ("64" in os.getenv('PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE')) in platform.architecture():
```

and

```
elif ("32" in os.getenv('PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE')) or ("32" in os.getenv('PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE')) in platform.architecture():
```

It works fine:

```
['Windows', '64-bit']
```

I've tried to find the answer everywhere, but I went flop...
Got any idea..?

Comment: Do you know what `"Windows" or "windows"` evaluates to?

Comment: yes) u can try to run this code with only 'Windows', the problem remains

Comment: `elif a == linux:` is not valid. You can't have `elif` without a preceding `if`. The indentation is off too. I'm surprised you're not mentioning any errors. `windows = "Windows" or "windows"` won't work they way you expect it too either (it will always be assigned to the first word. It's not some sort of boolean variable but a `str`ing.

Comment: this is my first question on stackoverflow, so I've 'copy-pasted' with bad syntax.. Sorry for it

Comment: The problem isn't in syntax, the problem is in 'duplication'. If u correctly write the code, it wouldn't work, works only: if A or A in B...

Comment: @OlegV. Write the code correctly, then run it, then I will believe you. I think you are attempting to pass off your lack of understanding of how the Python keywords work as a bug in the language.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I've edited the post with the code. As I said before "the problem remains". Never mind 'cause the "global" problem was a bit different, exactly global. I've received the satisfied answer for my question. Thank you for your comment

Comment: @OlegV. The selected answer is quite good. You will note that it begins with "You have a fundamental misunderstand of the basic logic operators."

Comment: @MadPhysicist of course. Не that never climbed never fell (c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a fundamental misunderstand of the basic logic operators. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) says that an `x or y` statement is evaluated as "if x is false, then y, else x". Think about that in the context of these statements from your code:

```
windows = "Windows" or "windows"
linux = "Linux" or "linux"
```

For each one, it will look at the string before the `or`. Since it is not a null string, it evaluates to `True`, and therefore `"Windows" or "windows"` evaluates to just `"Windows"`. Thus these two statements are identical to:

```
windows = "Windows"
linux = "Linux"
```

As it happens, you got lucky and `platform.system()` returned `"Windows"` and you made it into the correct branch of the outer `if` statement. Now comes the next issue:

```
if ("64" in os.getenv('PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE')) in platform.architecture():
```

I'm not sure exactly how you thought this would work, but `"64" in os.getenv('PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE')` is just going to evaluate to `True` (on 64-bit environments), therefore that line will be equivalent to:

```
if True in platform.architecture():
```

...which will not succeed, since there's no `True` object in a string.

The reason your "duplicated" line worked as you expected:

```
if ("64" in os.getenv('PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE')) or ("64" in os.getenv('PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE')) in platform.architecture():
```

...is because, as I mentioned, `"64" in os.getenv('PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE')` evaluates to `True`. Since that makes the part before the `or` true, the program is satisfied and moves into the `if` block without even bothering to look at what comes after.

**So how do you fix it?**

If you want to tell if a string matches one of a number of strings, you can use a list or tuple and `in`:

```
windows = ("Windows", "windows")

...

if a in windows:
```

As for the other one, I'm not entirely sure what you're actually trying to do, but removing the second `in` clause appears to do what you seem to want:

```
if "64" in os.getenv('PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE'):
```

Comment: thanks for an adequate explanation
it works fine and I've understood my biggest mistake in the code
may God grant you good health!